# How to manipulate this Iterable in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, iterable

I have a rdd:

```
val input = RDD[(Int, Iterable[(info1, info2)])]
```

what I need is:

```
RDD[(Int, Array[info2])]
```

now I'm trying

```
val output = input.mapValue(ele => ???.toArray)
```

???is something I have difficulty with, I don't know how can I get access to the tuple inside iterable and only take each of them to a array. Or did I do something wrong from choosing mapValue method?

Comment: Does ele._2 in the place of ??? work?

Comment: No, I have already tried that before

Comment: Why do you want and Array in the last step? Is not ok with a Seq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need an Array as a result, and it is ok with any type of Seq, maybe it is ok with something like this:

Given this example of data set:

```
val inputrdd = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, Iterable((101,102))), (2, Iterable((201,202))), (3, Iterable((301,302)))))
```

You can use a mapValue like this:

```
inputrdd.mapValues(iter => iter.map(_._2))
```

That it is equivalent to:

```
inputrdd.map{case(k,iter)=>(k,iter.map(_._2))}
```

`iter` is the iterable object and It's in the `map(_._2)` where you take the second part of the tuple.

In this point, you now how to access and manipulate the iterable. If you need, force an Array, you can do it:

```
inputrdd.mapValues(iter => iter.map(_._2).toArray)
```

Comment: thx, I have to use array as a result, but mapValue is not a mandatory.

Comment: @XinlinFeng I updated the response to forcing the type to an array, but think about that. It is better to use Seq to have an higher abstraction level. Scala is going to use the best implementation for you.

Comment: thx, I will consider about changing the type, I'm just beginner in scala